# Swift - TableView of steppers, click one stepper in a cell and other steppers get activated?

Tags: uitableview, swift, uistepper

I am new to IOS and basically I have a tableView and whenever it has 40 cells and each cell has a stepper and a label. the label displays the stepper's value. The tableview generates the cells fine, but the problem is that whenever I click the stepper in one cell, some other random cells also have their steppers activated.This is swift by the way. Here is the code for the cell:

```
import UIKit

class StudentTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
@IBOutlet weak var studentNameAndValue: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var studentValueChanger: UIStepper!

let name:String?
let value:Int?
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@IBAction func stepperValueChanged(sender: AnyObject) {
    studentNameAndValue.text = "\(name): \(Int(studentValueChanger.value))"
}

}
```

Here is the code for the viewcontroller:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 40
}
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("studentCell") as StudentTableViewCell
    return cell
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your table view controller. It would be better to put the value-changed method there. Alternatively, review your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You are not updating the cells correctly when they are recycled.

You have to set the value of stepper and label explicitly in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. You cannot read these values from the cell - they should be in your `datasource` (i.e. the table view controller should know what to display for a given index path).

Connect the stepper handler to the method in the view controller, then identify the proper index path via the `sender` argument.

```
@IBAction func stepperChanged(sender: UIStepper) {
    let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
    let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)!
    let myData = dataArray[indexPath.row] // or whatever your datasource
    // if you need to update the cell
    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
}
```

Comment: how would I put the value-changed method in the table view controller and connect it to the actual stepper and label?

Comment: Connect it in storyboard from the prototype cell. In the handler, you can identify the `sender`. I will add some code to my answer to demonstrate.

Comment: but if we are connecting the stepper and the label inside the view controller, we would have to connect them inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method. right?

Comment: No. The stepper is part of the dequeued cell already. You connect them in **storyboard**.

Comment: okay. so I don't have to put the stepperChanged method inside cellForRowAtIndexPath because I can already retrieve the point using sender

Comment: It still doesn't work. When I added the stepperChanged method in the view controller instead, it worked but other labels from other cells still changed too.

Comment: this is what the method looked like for testing:

Comment: @IBAction func stepperChangerMethod(sender: UIStepper) {
        let point = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: tableView)
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForRowAtPoint(point)
        let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!) as StudentTableViewCell
        cell.studentNameAndValue.text = ""
    }

Comment: Did you change the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method?

Comment: I can't put the IBAction inside cellForRowAtIndexPath method, It gives me an error, I have to put the IBAction outside cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: what should my cellForRowAtIndexPath method look like?

Comment: OK, slow down. If you tried that, you have not understood how the architecture works. Please read this thread carefully a couple of times and perhaps consult the documentation about the mentioned methods. Then try to implement it carefully while observing what you learned. Then, after you are done with that - post again to this thread if you need help.